# Make a template of an existant template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a template of an existant template. Is this possible ? How ?

I tried to use function declaration.

```
template<typename... Args> std::pair<char*, std::vector<void(*)(Args...)>> events_list;

events_list<ButtonEvent> button_event; // Doesn't work : pointer to function conversion.
```

I expect the result to be a simple on/emit event handler like this.

```
static void onClick(ButtonEvent e) {
    printf(e.buttonId);
}

events_list<ButtonEvent> button_event;
button_event.push_back(onClick);
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: For "function" object always use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), it will make your life much easier.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mimic how java OOP works. Kind advice: don't.

Comment: Thank you, I will try `std::function`. Why type alias ? I don't understand. Why sould not ? @YSC

Comment: @user11051353 java is java, C++ is C++. Most of the Java-ish idiom are being slowly replaced by idiom that better match the C++ way of doing things.

Comment: And `char*` should probably be `std::string` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean a template type alias?

If so, then you'll have to change the syntax a bit:

```
template<typename... Args>
using events_list = std::pair<char*, std::vector<void(*)(Args...)>>;
```

If you want to use `std::function` instead of pointer to function, try this:

```
template<typename... Args>
using events_list = std::pair<char*, std::vector<std::function<void(Args...)>>;
```

You also seem to want a convenient way of inserting new events. It will look a bit different if you go with the container you choosed:

```
// static member function are normal function pointers.
button_event.second.push_back(&YouClass::onClick);
```

Or you can also use a lambda. Without captures, both container will work:

```
button_event.second.push_back([](ButtonEvent e) {
    onClick(e);
});

// with captures (only work with the std::function)
button_event.second.push_back([this](ButtonEvent e) {
    this->onClickNonStatic(e);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, thanks to you two ! Is this a good way to do it because you say that it mimics the way the java OOP works ? Sorry but what's Java-Ish ?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot 

Comment: Well, it depends. It's hard to juge without the big picture. If you merly try to mimic the syntax (and the way it's implemented) then you may have a bad time (you know, no GC, lot's of new, etc.). If you try to offer a similar interface to make it look more simple, but move the complexity in the implementation. then it may worth it. But from experience, I was able to make things look better then when I tried to copy the idiom from one language to another. Of course, I was able to do that by iterating from what I knew.

Comment: I will look at what template can do before continuing. Thanks a lot for your help 